# Oracle - Deleting overlapping records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Due to mistake while populating a table with data there are erroneous records in the table now. In particular, there are overlapping timestamps. Now I want to delete the records, which have the characteristics shown in the following example:

[image]

```
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('1','3',to_timestamp('27.05.2016 17:27:08','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('31.05.2016 18:34:16','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('2','3',to_timestamp('31.05.2016 18:34:16','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('31.05.2016 18:34:26','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('3','3',to_timestamp('31.05.2016 18:34:26','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('01.06.2016 08:56:51','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('4','3',to_timestamp('01.06.2016 08:56:51','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('01.06.2016 18:38:30','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('5','3',to_timestamp('01.06.2016 18:38:30','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('08.06.2016 15:23:22','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('6','3',to_timestamp('08.06.2016 15:23:22','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('08.06.2016 21:02:21','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('7','3',to_timestamp('08.06.2016 17:09:02','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('08.06.2016 19:04:05','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('8','3',to_timestamp('08.06.2016 19:04:05','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('08.06.2016 21:02:21','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('9','3',to_timestamp('08.06.2016 21:02:21','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('09.09.9999 00:00:00','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('10','6',to_timestamp('20.06.2016 21:23:48','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('20.06.2016 21:23:56','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('11','6',to_timestamp('20.06.2016 21:23:56','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('21.06.2016 08:59:16','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('12','6',to_timestamp('21.06.2016 08:22:35','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('21.06.2016 08:23:02','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('13','6',to_timestamp('21.06.2016 08:23:02','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('21.06.2016 08:59:16','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('14','6',to_timestamp('21.06.2016 08:59:16','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('21.06.2016 12:06:49','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('15','6',to_timestamp('21.06.2016 12:06:49','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('22.06.2016 06:29:51','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('16','6',to_timestamp('22.06.2016 06:29:51','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('22.06.2016 08:18:18','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('17','6',to_timestamp('22.06.2016 08:18:18','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('22.06.2016 08:24:58','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('18','6',to_timestamp('22.06.2016 08:24:58','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('22.06.2016 08:38:18','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into TEST_OVERLAP (TICKET_SK,TICKET_ID,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) values ('19','6',to_timestamp('22.06.2016 08:38:18','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('09.09.9999 00:00:00','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
```

The amount of records to delete could also be larger than 2 per ticket_id.

How could this be done?

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: Please post sample data as formatted text, not images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood you want to delete every record that have a record with same `ticket_id` and a timeframe that completely contains the record.

Here's a query that do the job:

```
DELETE tickets t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tickets t2
    WHERE t2.ticket_id  =  t.ticket_id
      AND t2.valid_from <  t.valid_from
      AND t2.valid_to   >= t.valid_to
);
```